# .wlnet file is not available now?

Tags: bugs, export, import, neural-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and fixed in 13.0 or earlier**

---

After I run this code in *Mathematica 11.2*

```
net = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"];
Export["digital.wlnet", net]
```

Then I try to import it with this code

[image]

As the message see, I cannot use this file..Have I missed something or it is a bug?

Comment: Nothing changed.It still a file format in MMA

Comment: sometimes, I see this error information when `NetModel['model_name']` where model is downloaded partly.